# How to style the Download button in Shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps

I have created a `download button` in my `Shiny` app. However I want *NOT to change* the background colour when clicked, which is not happening here. Below is my app -

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
ui <- shinyUI( dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(
    title="Styling Download Button"
  ),
  dashboardSidebar(
    tags$style(type="text/css", "#download1 {background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0);color: black;font-family: Courier New}"),
    downloadButton("download1", label="Download with style", class = "butt1")
  ),
  dashboardBody()
))
#server.r
server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Any idea on how to keep background colour exactly same on click will be highly helpful.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can make sure the `#download1:active` (on click) style equals the `#download1` (normal) style as follows.
In the below example, I also made sure that the `border-color` is fixed such that no on-click effect is visible whatsoever.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
ui <- shinyUI( dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(
    title="Styling Download Button"
  ),
  dashboardSidebar(
    tags$style(type="text/css",
               "#download1, #download1:active  {
      background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0);
      color: black;
      font-family: Courier New;
      border-color: #ddd;
      -webkit-box-shadow: 0px;
      box-shadow: 0px;
    }
   "),
    downloadButton("download1", label="Download with style", class = "butt1")
  ),
  dashboardBody()
))
#server.r
server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanks, this improves. But I still see some shadow near the top and left borders, which I also want to eliminate. I tried with adding border: 0px; box-shadow: 0px; - but none is not working. Any idea what style I need to apply to eliminate those?

Comment: I think you need to add both `-webkit-box-shadow` and `box-shadow`, see edit

Comment: Not very sure even using webkit the shadow is going off entirely